# How can do functionality of notify for controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use MVC pattern .
I've `UIView`, `CuctomViewController` and `ModelOfCuctomViewController`.

ModelOfCuctomViewController creates data for my CuctomViewController and take data from some web server because I've small delay.
The question is. How can I notify CuctomViewController after update of `ModelOfCuctomViewController`.

I'm using`KVC` pattern for notify my controller about some changes in model now. And I can use  NSNotification.

Maybe, Does  somebody know another options functionality for notify controller?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - please clarify your question and include code showing what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the prefered way of doing this is using NSNotifications, but KVC or protocol/delegate are good approaches too. I don't think Apple stablishes anything in particular.

> Communication: User actions in the view layer that create or modify
>   data are communicated through a controller object and result in the
>   creation or updating of a model object. When a model object changes
>   (for example, new data is received over a network connection), it
>   notifies a controller object, which updates the appropriate view objects.